# With statement query causes duplication error, but if works normal using regular delete and insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have a table where I must upsert data. Because there are too many column I decided to delete and insert new ones. when I am executing this query its falls because of duplicate unique key

```
const factionNames = parsedProfileData.map(p => p.faction_name);
const test = `With del as (DELETE "${tableNames.FACTION_PROFILE}" WHERE "faction_name" = ANY($1::text[]))
                         INSERT INTO "${tableNames.PLAYER_PROFILE}" ${auroraDB.createInsertString(parsedProfileData)};`
await auroraDB.client.query(test, [factionNames])
```

but it normally executes this ones

```
const deleteQuery = `DELETE FROM "${tableNames.FACTION_PROFILE}" WHERE "faction_name" = ANY($1::text[]);`
const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO "${tableNames.FACTION_PROFILE}" ${auroraDB.createInsertString(parsedProfileData)}`;
await auroraDB.openTransaction() //BEGIN TRANSACTION;
await auroraDB.client.query(deleteQuery, [factionNames]);
await auroraDB.client.query(insertQuery)
await auroraDB.closeTransaction() //COMMIT
```

also the same without opening and closing transaction manually.

Why?It is working with about 4000 rows, can it be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected and documented behaviour.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), **so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So the INSERT part sees the table as if no DELETE has happened, and that's why the duplicate key error happens.

Comment: Wow, bcs of small amount of data i was always thinking that that is is working synchronous, thank you

Comment: Nice One. so we have to take care of while using `insert`/`delete`/`update` using `with`